# Is there a way to specify "unserialize function" in a serialized string in php?

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

In my php code, I want to serialize various kinds of objects and store the resulting strings in database. When I read the string back, I want to unserialize the string in different ways depending on the data. So, I want a way specify a function identifier in the serialized string. That particular function should be used in order to deserialize the string. My friend said that python's serialization function supports this behavior. I am curious to know if there is a built-in PHP mechanism which does this?

So, I am expecting a behavior a like this.

```
$string1 = serialize($obj1, func1);
$string2 = serialize($obj2, func2);

$obj3 = unserialize($string1);  //Should call func1($string1);
$obj4 = unserialize($string2);  //Should call func2($string2);
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/45455299/2191572

Comment: and/or https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup